# Django not showing all mysql database results despite using fetchall method

Tags: django

I have ten records in mysql database and am using `fetchall()` method

Now I have requirements to display all database result in json using sql queries in django.

When I run the code below, it only shows the first records while the rest is not displayed.

I was wondering why am  getting just only one json record despite using **fetchall()** approach

**Here is the code**

```
from django.db import connection
def read(request):
    sql = 'SELECT * from crud_posts'
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
         cursor.execute(sql)
         output = cursor.fetchall()
         print(output[0])
         items=[]
         for row in output: 
             items.append({'id':row[0], 'title': row[1],'content': row[2]})

             jsondata = json.dumps({'items': items})
             return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Fix your identation...you are returning a response after the first loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exiting the for loop after the first iteration...fix your identation:

```
from django.db import connection

def read(request):
    sql = 'SELECT * from crud_posts'
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
         cursor.execute(sql)
         output = cursor.fetchall()
         print(output[0])
         items=[]
         for row in output: 
             items.append({'id':row[0], 'title': row[1],'content': row[2]})

         jsondata = json.dumps({'items': items})
         return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: Sir Drec4s, please I need your help on this issue. Thanks      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395675/some-comments-are-missing-when-looped-through-mysql-records-via-django