# Some comments are missing when looped through MySQL records via Django

Tags: django

I have requirements to display posts and comments results from database in JSON using SQL queries via Django.

Below is my expected JSON format:

```
[
{"id":"1","title":"post title 1","content":"post content 1.","comment":[{"comment":"comment 1 post 1."},{"comment":"comment 2 post 1."}]},
{"id":"2","title":"post title 2.","content":"post content 2","comment":[{"comment":"comment3 post 2."}]},
{"id":"3","title":"post title 3","content":"post content 3","comment":[]}
]
```

When I run the code below, all the post records are displayed with some comment missing. Here is what I have:

```
[
{"id": 1, "title": "post title 1", "content": "post content 1.", "comment": {"comid": 4, "comment": "coment 4 for post 1"}}, 
{"id": 2, "title": "post title 2.", "content": "post content 2", "comment": {"comid": 3, "comment": "coment 3 for post 2"}},
{"id": 3, "title": "post title 3", "content": "post content 3", "comment": {"comid": 3, "comment": "coment 3 for post 2"}}
]
```

### My issues

Some comments are missing in the arrays. For instance:

1. **post with id 1** should have two comments in the array but am just seeing one comment attached to the postid.
2. **Post with id 3** does not have any comment but am seeing comments attached to its postid

I was wondering if this issue has to do with indentation when exiting for loop.

Here is the code:

```
def read(request):
    sql = 'SELECT * from crud_posts'
    with connection.cursor() as cursor1:
         cursor1.execute(sql)
         output = cursor1.fetchall()
         #print(output[0])
         items=[]
         for row in output: 
             postid = row[0]
             #Get comments
             sql2 = "SELECT * from crud_comment where postid= %s"
             pid = (postid)
             with connection.cursor() as cursor2:
                  cursor2.execute(sql2, pid)
                  output2 = cursor2.fetchall()
                  items2=[]
                  for row2 in output2:
                      comment_array = {'comid':row2[0], 'comment': row2[3]}
                      #comment_array = items2.append({'comid':row2[0], 'comment': row2[3]})
                      print('this is comment array:', comment_array)

             items.append({'id':row[0], 'title': row[1],'content': row[2], 'comment': comment_array})
         jsondata = json.dumps({'items': items})
         return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

Here is the **models.py**:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " " + self.content


class Comment(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    postid = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.userid + " " + self.postid
```

Comment: where is `comments` key in your code? and in  `comment_array = {'comid':row2[0], 'comment': row2[3]}` that is not a list or array it is a dictionary are you sure you want this? you will always see one comment like this as it is single dictionary maybe you want list of dictionaries right?

Comment: Why don't you just use foreign keys for your `userid` and `postid` fields? It would make everything easier.

Comment: And why are you using raw SQL rather than Django model methods?

Comment: @Yugandhar Chaudhari yes.

Comment: using django orm will make it easier you will just need to use serializer then no need to format json by yourself

Comment: @ Sir Daniel Roseman. I have tried Django Model but with almost the same result. will you like to see the code

Comment: Yes. And didn't I already tell you to change your userid and postid fields to ForeignKeys?

Comment: @Sir Daniel Roseman.  I remembered  Foreign key. You are the best in the world

Comment: Thanks everyone for amazing contribution. God bless you all

Comment: The use of foreign keys as suggested by @Sir Daniel Roseman is what solved the problem